org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Value schema must be of type Struct
I recieve the data in my topic like this :
{"C_IST":"1",
"C_AG":"00",
"C_TP_RAPP":"1",
"N_RAPP":"3587",
"C_SCATG_RAPP":{"string":"09"},
"S_ITZ":{"string":"مؤ"},
"SLD_CNT":{"long":962},
"ARROT":{"string":"000"},
"C_SETTS":{"string":"st"},
"DT_APER_RAPP":{"string":"0430"},
"DT_ESTZ_RAPP":null,
"N_ASS_FRNC":{"string":"0"},
"N_ASS_USF":{"string":"0"},
"C_PERD_STMP":{"string":"2"},
"C_TP_QUI":{"string":"3"},
"N_CASL":{"int":0},
"N_PEZ":{"string":"0"},
"BLC_RILS_CRNT":{"string":"0"},
"C_CNV":{"string":"08   "},
"C_DV":{"string":"8"},
"NDG":{"string":"32533"},
"STMP_TP":{"string":"1"},
"STMP_VAL":{"string":"1"},
"C_INDI":{"string":"24147"},
"INIT_SLD_CNT":{"long":0},
"MIGR_DT":{"string":"        "},
"ARCH_INIT_SLD_CNT":{"long":0},
"ARCH_MIGR_DT":{"string":"        "},
"C_MATR":{"string":"CON3189"},
"IBAN":{"string":"SA45315587"},
"F_TIT_LIBR_ASS":{"string":"0"},
"CDC_TIMESTAMP":{"string":"200000"},
"ODS_KFK_TIMESTAMP":{"string":"2000000000"},
"OPERATION_TYPE":{"string":"UP"}}

and the connector expect data of type struct ,
i configure this connector :
`class: io.aiven.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
  config:
    value.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    topics: snpdh_08
    value.converter.schemas.enable: false
    connection.password: E*********
    pk.fields: 'C_AG,C_IST,C_TP_RAPP,N_RAPP'
    key.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
    pk.mode: record_value
    tasksMax: 2
    insert.mode: UPSERT
    table.name.format: EUNT.I208
    connection.user: EMKAT
    auto.create: false
    auto.evolve: true
    key.converter.schemas.enable: false
    pk.schemas: true
    connection.url: >-
      jdbc:oracle:thin:***********************************************************`

but i still having issue : Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: PK mode for table 'ICSR1208' is RECORD_VALUE, but record value schema is missing
and if i also require  to change my data to actually have a schema , how can i do it.
